# Scrapy Crawler working in shell but not in code

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Hello I am trying to build a simple crawler from scrapy.

The code works fine in scrapy shell but when I run it through console it doesn't write anything to json file.

I am running it from project top directory as

```
scrapy crawl filemare -o filemare.json


import scrapy


class FilemareSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "filemare"
    allowed_domains = ['https://filemare.com/']
    start_urls = ["https://filemare.com/en-
                   us/search/firmware%20download/632913359"]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.xpath('//div[@class="f"]/text()').extract()
        #items = response.css('div.f::text').extract()

        for url in items:
            print(url)
            yield url
```

Answer (score 1):

`parse` method has to return a `dict`, Scrapy `Item` or a `Request` object (see the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)). In your case, you yield a string. If you run the spider, you'll see an error in the output.

Change the corresponding part of the code like this:

```
...
def parse(self, response):
    items = response.xpath('//div[@class="f"]/text()').extract()

    for url in items:
        print(url)
        yield {'url': url}
```

Comment: Thanks that was useful. But my crawler was getting disabled because of robots.txt file. Need to change the setting file to  ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

Comment: Really? When I tried your code myself, crawling proceeded and yielding was the only problem.